# Can Rupture cause a chain reaction?

Tags: diablo-iii

**Example:**

**Cleave:** Swing in a wide arc to deal 120% weapon damage to the targeted enemy and 60% weapon damage to any other enemies caught in the swing.

**Rupture(Cleave Rune):** Enemies slain by this attack have a 100% chance to explode, causing 150 physical damage to all other enemies within 19 yards.

Once I kill an enemy and he explodes and kills an enemy will that enemy explode as well creating a chain reaction, or is it only the enemy that is *directly* slain by the cleave that will explode?

Comment: I tested it on beta, and was chain type. Don't know if it's the same now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, Rupture cannot cause a chain reaction.**

I just finished testing this, here is the method that I used:

1. Purchase a weapon with a low damage spread (high minimum and low maximum damage). This is important to distinguish between damage caused by Cleave (which does 120% weapon damage) and damage caused by the Rupture explosion (which does 85% weapon damage). If there is too large of a spread, it becomes difficult to tell in the videos which one is which. In this case, Cleave did around 43-47 damage against skeletons and Rupture did 27-31 or so.
   The weapon I purchased for this is called a Fleet Hulk:
   [image: Fleet Hulk]
2. Run around in the Cathedral for several hours trying to find the ideal group of enemies, taking video and analyzing it for places where Rupture should be spreading but isn't.
3. Upload and annotate the video ([Here it is!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNbbJ6Z3Y98)). If anyone sees anything in the video that makes my conclusion seem incorrect, please let me know and I will try running more tests.

I captured quite a few other segments where Rupture also didn't chain, but in those cases it seemed like there was some doubt since the enemies were a bit more scattered. This video seemed like the most conclusive test since the enemies (especially the group on the right) are quite closely grouped but still don't cause any additional Ruptures despite an enemy dying from Rupture damage right beside them.

Note: In case you're wondering how far 8 yards (the range for Rupture) is in the game, here is a [handy image](http://diablo.incgamers.com/gallery/data/632/D3_Distance_Map.jpg).

Edit: Apparently the annotations got messed up on the Youtube video, I'll try to post a new version when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it still is that way.

If you want to confirm it for yourself, you should test it on a pack of small enemies, such as the spiderlings in Act I. It's pretty easilty observable there.

Comment: Aren't you missing an actual answer here?